# Can your devices auto connect to your iOS hotspot without opening the settings/hotspot screen?

Tags: ios, network, wifi, car-integration

My car (VW Passat 2016) relies on a hotspot from a smartphone to have internet for all it's internet services (like traffic info).
After enabling hotspot on my iPhone (iOS 9.3) my car can connect and everything works fine. The problem is that my car (or any other device) can't connect to my iPhone's hotspot (which I leave enabled) unless I manually open the Settings app and then go to the hotspot settings screen.
I discussed this with a couple of friends and they all seem to have the same experience. This is really disappointing and I don't see myself doing this whole process everything I get into my car...

What about you? Is there fix?

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same issue here. Have a feeling that the iphone is blocking the car from re-connecting to the wifi hotspot. Has anyone spoken to their VW dealer about this?